# How to get date with extra month from datepicker in jquery

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

Let I have a input box where I apply date picker Now I want to get selected date with adding extra month to show another place

**example**

//adding 11 month

if i select `2015-04-01` then I want to get output `2016-03-01`

But I get something like that `2015-14-01`

**what I tried**

```
$("#loanDisbursmentDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect:function(date,dtObj){
             var day = $("#loanDisbursmentDate").datepicker('getDate').getDate();                 
             var month = $("#loanDisbursmentDate").datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 11;             
             var year = $("#loanDisbursmentDate").datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();
             var fulldate =   year + '-' + month + '-' +day;
             console.log(fulldate); 

        }
});
```

Comment: var month = $("#loanDisbursmentDate").datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 11;  in this line change 11 to 12 and check.

Comment: I got your point But it when I add 11 with 4 month it should change the year coz `11+4 = 15  month` which is `1 year and 3 month`

Comment: i put some example down, please have a look.

Comment: check my updated answer it might be help you @Md.SahadatHossain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/XtbYz/458/)

Html

Change to below code

```
 $("#loanDisbursmentDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect:function(dateText,instance){
              date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);
            date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 11);
             $(".secondcal").datepicker("setDate", date);

            $('#displayDate').html($('.secondcal').val());

        }
});

$(".secondcal").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
```

Comment: if I want show this date in another place not input box what to do?

Comment: just u can use `$('.seondval').val()` you can get the value and use where the value u need

Comment: But I dont have second input box. I have only one input box and a p tag. when a date select in input box then I want show my desire output in p tag

Answer (score 1):

All you are doing is selecting the day, month and year values of the date adding a value and printing it out its the same as doing 4 + 11 on the month. There is no reference to a date after that point so the assumption is that the month can be greater than 12. Try the following:

```
$("#loanDisbursmentDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect:function(date,dtObj){
         var date = $("#loanDisbursmentDate").datepicker('getDate')
         var day = date.getDate();                 
         var month = date.getMonth() + 11;             
         var year = date.getFullYear();
         var fulldate = new Date();
         fulldate.setYear(year);
         fulldate.setMonth(month);
         fulldate.setDate(day);
         console.log(fulldate.toString("yyyy-mm-dd")); 

    }
});
```